# Enterprise Library 4.1 Assemblies

Tags: .net, enterprise-library

I recently just downloaded Microsoft Enterprise Library 4.1 – October 2008 and in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203283.aspx) it claimed that it includes Microsoft-signed strong name assemblies.

I cannot find these in the extract, where are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Enterprise Library 4.1 - October 2008\Bin`

Comment: Ah thanks, I didn't know it was extracted there. I assumed it was just in C:\EntLib41Src. Thanks Christian.

Answer (score 0):

If the assemblies don't exist within the extracted folder find BuildLibraryAndCopyAssemblies.bat and run it. Files will be located in the previous post location.

> BuildLibrary.bat. This file compiles all application blocks and tools. When launched with no parameters, it builds a Debug version of the application blocks and tools. It accepts one parameter to indicate an alternative build type, such as a Release build.
>
> CopyAssemblies.bat. This file copies the assemblies to the bin directory. When launched with no parameters, it copies the Debug assemblies to the INSTALLDIR\Program Files\Microsoft Enterprise Library\bin directory. It accepts two parameters. The first parameter indicates an alternative build type, and the second parameter indicates the destination directory where the assemblies will be copied.
>
> BuildLibraryAndCopyAssemblies.bat. This file sequentially executes BuildLibrary.bat and CopyAssemblies.bat.

Comment: I got the solution, but I was looking for Microsoft-signed assemblies. The BuildLibraryAndCopyAssemblies are for signing it yourself when you want to modify the source of the library. Thanks though.